# Beam break and rest height problems in ABCjs

Tags: notation, software, rests, beaming, abc-notation

In the below ABCjs sample:

```
X: 1
T: Symphony No. 7
C: Gustav Mahler (1860-1911)
R: Langsam (Adagio)
M: 4/4
L: 1/4
K: Bm
[F,^G,B,D]/z//[F,G,B,D]///[F,G,B,D]/// [F,G,B,D]/z//[F,G,B,D]///[F,G,B,D]/// !///![F,G,B,D]2 |
```

1. How can I make both the note beams and the semiquaver rests lower?
2. How do I break the beam between the first set of semidemiquavers and the second quaver?

ABCjs code:

```
    X: 1
    T: Symphony No. 7
    C: Gustav Mahler (1860-1911)
    R: Langsam (Adagio)
    M: 4/4
    L: 1/4
    K: Bm
    [F,^G,B,D]/z//[F,G,B,D]///[F,G,B,D]/// [F,G,B,D]/z//[F,G,B,D]///[F,G,B,D]/// !///![F,G,B,D]2 |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any proper solution to either of your questions in the ABC standard. The beam ought to be split with the code as you posted it, but it looks to me like there's a bug in the ABCjs typesetting. A workaround seems to be to change the default note length. The length of the stems is determined by the typesetting engine, and can't be configured.

```
X: 1
T: Symphony No. 7
C: Gustav Mahler (1860-1911)
R: Langsam (Adagio)
M: 4/4
L: 1/8
K: Bm
[F,^G,B,D]z/[F,G,B,D]//[F,G,B,D]// [F,G,B,D]z/[F,G,B,D]//[F,G,B,D]// !///![F,G,B,D]4 |
```

```
    X: 1
    T: Symphony No. 7
    C: Gustav Mahler (1860-1911)
    R: Langsam (Adagio)
    M: 4/4
    L: 1/8
    K: Bm
    [F,^G,B,D]z/[F,G,B,D]//[F,G,B,D]// [F,G,B,D]z/[F,G,B,D]//[F,G,B,D]// !///![F,G,B,D]4 |
```

Comment: The "workaround" you mention _is_ the answer I needed; it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

I'm the maintainer for abcjs. I just happened to stumble on this question, and can confirm that the beam not breaking is a bug, as is the height of the rests. I fixed those bugs in the latest version, so if you upgrade to abcjs v3.3.0, the problem will go away. Please feel free to post future bugs to the abcjs project page https://github.com/paulrosen/abcjs/issues if you see anything else unusual.